# What is the purpose of lambda in this example?

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming

lambda is used in this example in both the compose and the hydrate methods. What does lambda do here?

```
def compose *lambdas
  if lambdas.empty?
    lambda { nil }
  elsif lambdas.size == 1
    lambdas.first
  else
    lambda do |n|
      lambdas.first.call(compose(*lambdas[1..-1]).call(n))
    end
  end
end

def hydrate(modulus, printable_form)
  i = 0
  lambda do |n|
    (i = (i + 1) % modulus) == 0 && printable_form || n
  end
end

print(((1..100).map
   &compose(
     hydrate(15, 'Watermelon'), 
     hydrate(5, 'Melon'), 
     hydrate(3, 'Water'))).join(' '))
```

My second question is - what is the need for the ampersand in front of the word compose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `compose` takes a list of functions and returns a newly allocated function that is the composition of all the functions on the list.  It's been written to treat the empty list rather oddly; it may be that the first case should be ignored.  (Normally composing the empty list of functions should produce the identity function, but that's not what your example does.  I would have expected

```
lambda do |n| { n }
```

as the base case.)

It's necessary to use a `lambda` in order to **create a new function**  You see that in the recursive case in compose: the `lambda` creates a new function which when given `n` returns the result of calling the composition of the remaining functions, then finally applies the first function.  This is not good code to emulate, as **the recursion over the list of functions is repeated every time the composition is called**.  In the example:

- Creating the composition of functions uses constant time and space
- Applying the composition of functions costs linear time and space

Whereas if the code were written properly

- Creating the composition of functions *should* cost linear time and space
- Applying the composition of functions *should* cost linear time and should require no allocations (zero space)

Unfortunately I don't know enough Ruby to write for you an example of `compose` the way it ought to be done.  But others will.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note, I don't know where you got this exact code, but it looks like a very lightly altered version of some code from Reginald Braithwaite's blog. (The code was a deliberately over-the-top solution to the FizzBuzz question used in a serious discussion of functional programming in Ruby and functional programming more generally.)

Here are the original posts:

- [Don't Overthink FizzBuzz](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/01/dont-overthink-fizzbuzz.html)
- [Closures and Higher-Order Functions](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/01/closures-and-higher-order-functions.html)

Answer (score 5):

Your second question asks what the `&` is doing.

Looking at [The unary ampersand in Ruby](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html), the ampersand converts a proc to a block.

Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> def meth1
irb(main):002:1>   yield "Hello"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
```

Calling meth1 with a block, works as expected:

```
irb(main):004:0> meth1 { |s| puts s } # Calling meth1 with a block
Hello
=> nil
```

Calling with a Proc does not work:

```
irb(main):005:0> p = Proc.new { |s| puts "In proc: #{s}" }
=> #<Proc:0x13e5d60@(irb):5>
irb(main):006:0> meth1 p
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby19/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But it does work if you convert the Proc to a block:

```
irb(main):007:0> meth1 &p # Convert the proc to a block
In proc: Hello
=> nil
```

This is the same thing that is happening when you use the following code:

```
irb(main):001:0> def meth2(&block) # Block is converted to Proc
irb(main):002:1>   puts block.class.to_s if block_given?
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> meth2 { puts "Hi There" }
Proc
=> nil
irb(main):005:0>
```

Here is another article on the differences between blocks, [block vs lambda vs proc](http://neeraj.name/blog/articles/589-block-vs-lambda-vs-proc).